# sql subquery where in does not work ( at snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I try to create a table with moving current three month by using subquery for only selecting current 3 months.

I have

```
`select * from dataTable where month in 
(select max(month),max(month)-1,max(month)-2 from month_table);`
```

snowflake returns me this error msg
**SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 26 Invalid argument types for function '=': (NUMBER(6,0), ROW(NUMBER(6,0), NUMBER(7,0), NUMBER(7,0)))**

not sure what I miss. when I ran a query for that 3 current months by

```
select max(month),max(month)-1,max(month)-2 from month_table
```

it does return three months
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACv27.png)

any idea? or any alternative approach for getting data with moving three months is appreciated.

thanks

btw, subquery works only in one month
eg: select xxxx from (select max(month) from xxx)
so I am now using a clumsy union for 3 queries
select xxx from max(month) union select xxx from max(month)-1 union select xxx from max(month)-2...

so any better efficient approach is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sub query for In clause requires rows with each value you want to look up. So, Please try the following:

```
select * from dataTable where month in 
(select max(month)   from month_table union all
 select max(month)-1 from month_table union all
 select max(month)-2 from month_table
);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put a subquery in your where clause to get the max. (Optionally) create some test data based on your picture:

```
create or replace table dataTable as
select replace(left(dateadd('month', -1 * (row_number() over (order by 1) - 1), '2022-11-01')::string,7), '-', '')::int CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH
from table(generator(rowcount=>100));
```

Now just put a subquery in the where clause to get how many months you want in your result:

```
select * from dataTable
where CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH > (select max(CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH) - 3 from dataTable)
;
```

| CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH |
| --- |
| 202211 |
| 202210 |
| 202209 |

Answer (score 0):

When using `IN`:

```
where month in 
(select max(month),max(month)-1,max(month)-2 from month_table)
```

you are trying to perform:

```
WHERE (col) IN ((val1, val2, val3))
```

and by definition single element cannot be equal to 3-elements tuple.

[IN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/in.html#parameters):

> ```
> ( <value_A> [, <value_B> ... ] ) [ NOT ] IN (  ( <value_1> [ , <value_2> ... ] )  [ , ( <value_3> [ , <value_4> ... ] )  ...  ]  )
> ```
>
> value_A, value_B
>
> The elements of a row constructor for which to search.
>
> **Ensure that each value on the right of IN (e.g. (value3, value4)) has the same number of elements as the value on the left of IN (e.g. (value_A, value_B)).**

---

To make it work the query should be organized to match:

```
WHERE (col) IN ((val1), (val2), (val3))
```

i.e.,

```
WHERE month IN (SELECT max(month) FROM month_table UNION
                SELECT max(month)-1 FROM month_table UNION
                SELECT max(month)-2 FROM month_table)
```

or simpler as:

```
WHERE month BETWEEN (SELECT max(month)-2 FROM month_table) 
                AND (SELECT max(month)   FROM month_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using variables? That way you can pass those months as a list

```
set (m0,m1,m2) = (select max(month),max(month)-1,max(month)-2 from month_table);

select * 
from dataTable 
where month in ($m0,$m1,$m2);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first concern is that, you have dates as ether strings or numbers, and then are doing integer math on them, and seems to expect you will get valid results:

here I list a years worth of dates, and then convert them to the same `yyyymm` number format you have, and then subtract 2, & 3 like you do, but also show what that date with the subtraction is. which all points to the representation you have is wildly dangerous.

```
select 
    column1::date as as_date
    ,to_char(as_date, 'yyyymm')::int as_num
    ,as_num -2 as minus_2
    ,as_num -3 as minus_3
    ,dateadd('month', -3, as_date) as date_minus_3
from values 
    ('2022-12-01'),('2022-11-01'),
    ('2022-10-01'),('2022-09-01'),
    ('2022-08-01'),('2022-07-01'),
    ('2022-06-01'),('2022-05-01'),
    ('2022-04-01'),('2022-03-01'),
    ('2022-02-01'),('2022-01-01'), 
    ('2021-12-01')
order by 1 desc;
```

gives:

| AS_DATE | AS_NUM | MINUS_2 | MINUS_3 | DATE_MINUS_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | 202212 | 202210 | 202209 | 2022-09-01 |
| 2022-11-01 | 202211 | 202209 | 202208 | 2022-08-01 |
| 2022-10-01 | 202210 | 202208 | 202207 | 2022-07-01 |
| 2022-09-01 | 202209 | 202207 | 202206 | 2022-06-01 |
| 2022-08-01 | 202208 | 202206 | 202205 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2022-07-01 | 202207 | 202205 | 202204 | 2022-04-01 |
| 2022-06-01 | 202206 | 202204 | 202203 | 2022-03-01 |
| 2022-05-01 | 202205 | 202203 | 202202 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2022-04-01 | 202204 | 202202 | 202201 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-03-01 | 202203 | 202201 | 202200 | 2021-12-01 |
| 2022-02-01 | 202202 | 202200 | 202199 | 2021-11-01 |
| 2022-01-01 | 202201 | 202199 | 202198 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-12-01 | 202112 | 202110 | 202109 | 2021-09-01 |

notice that `Jan 2022` minus `3` is `Nov 2021` not the `99th month of 2021`

And given the need to do multiple sub-queries, and value ranges, I would always go the BETWEEN version that Lukasz shows last (for the BETWEEN being explicit about what you are intending)

```
WHERE month BETWEEN (SELECT to_char(dateadd('month', -3, to_date(max(month)::text,'YYYYMM')), 'yyyymm')::int FROM month_table) 
                AND (SELECT max(month)   FROM month_table)
```

but you can move the math, from `a between x-2 and x` to x between to `x between a-2 and a` thus

```
WHERE (SELECT max(month) FROM month_table) BETWEEN to_char(dateadd('month', -3, to_date(month::text,'YYYYMM')), 'yyyymm')::int
                AND month
```

the above is assuming `month` is an int based on the -1 and -2

which I would also write with alias's so it clear what is what:

```
select * 
from dataTable as d
where (select max(m.month) from month_table as m) between to_char(dateadd('month', -3, to_date(d.month::text,'YYYYMM')), 'yyyymm')::int
                AND d.month
```

Answer (score 0):

As most comments point out, your query returns the data in a row rather than a column, which results in that error message.

If the month is at a right format like NUMER, try this. **(I feel this might be the most concise code)**

```
select * from dataTable where MONTH in (select distinct top 3 month from month_table DESC)
```